# WCF Service: Call first function, return from it, then call second function to work in background

Tags: c#, database, wcf, synchronous

I am writing a WCF Service in which I have to call two functions to update the database but I want to return after first table update so that client should not wait longer and then second table will update in background.

The thing I want to do is like this:

```
public bool myMainFunction(){

    bool result = updateTable1();

    return result;

    updateTable2();

}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public bool MyMainFunction()
{
    bool result = UpdateTable1();

    Task.Run(() => UpdateTable2());

    return result;    
}
```

Task.Run(Action action)
From : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx

> Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool and returns a Task object that represents that work.

Basically, Task.Run queues your item on the threadpool - which allows it to run asynchronously. Usually you would pair this with the task's *Wait* or *Result* methods to block the calling thread until the task has finished - for example :

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public bool MyMainFunction()
{
    Task<bool> task = Task.Run(() => UpdateTable1());

    Task.Run(() => UpdateTable2());

    return task.Result;
}
```

In the previous example - both methods are now queued on the Threadpool - which means they can executed in parallel. (In the first example - UpdateTable1 had to finish before UpdateTable2 began - but we fired and forgot about UpdateTable2 - so it was inconsequential). The new example now allows UpdateTable2 to begin executing **before** UpdateTable1 has finished. However - we would now have a problem - as we need to wait for the result of UpdateTable1 to return the bool value required.

When you call either, **task.Wait()** or **task.Result**, your method basically pauses until the task has finished - in this case, it waits until table1 has updated.

Now - you'll notice we don't have a variable to store the state of UpdateTable2's tasks - this is because you don't care about the result. Since there is no variable stored we don't ever block the calling thread to view the result - which means that you've effectively got a "Fire and Forget" method.

Hopefully this helps clear it up a bit - but if not there are plenty of resources out there to help, look into Asynchronous and Parallel programming as there will be people out there who can explain more clearly than I.

The following has been useful to me :
[mcsd-certification-toolkit-exam-70-483](http://amzn.eu/iA6OvH5)

I have also converted your method names from Camel Case to Pascal Case, as this is standard practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hats off to you!